Re-checked luggage process in BOS, EWR or JFK for Delta or JetBlue (also, why is it so hard to find this info)?
Final Update:
My question was about specific combination of airlines / airports and luggage transfers.
What I learned from asking this question was the term 'interline agreements' (thanks to @jcaron sticking with me through different iterations of this question).
So what I needed to know was the term and how to search for it.
@jcaron suggested a paid service (with a free trial), if there are any other systems that allow to query this data, that would be a great addition to the answer section.

Below is the latest iteration of my not-very-well-formed question, for easy reference.
What this question is NOT:

It's not a generic question about International flight arrivals in the US and the need to pick up the bags before passing through customs and then re-checking them.
This is not a generic question about how things should work in the airport or assumptions about how things work.

What this question IS:

With the combination of airlines and airports listed below, how specifically does baggage recheck work?

As in:
x = Arriving at US International Airport
y = Domestic flight airline
w = US inbound international flight by an airline != y
the question is:
With x + y + w (above) = can check baggage right after customs?
OR must take luggage to Y's terminal and check-in there?

combinations I'm considering:



Airports/Airlines
Delta
JetBlue




BOS
1
2


EWR
3
4


JFK
5
6





So #2 means: Arriving at BOS with the connecting domestic flight operated by JetBlue.
I'm completely clueless about #1 and #2, because I don't have any experience arriving in BOS, and with #4 as I've only ever connected with JetBlue in JFK.
To summarize:
This is basically 6 questions rolled into one. Each of the questions is about the exact combination of airport and airline.
If this keeps on confusing everyone, I'll post the airport/airline combinations as separate questions.
Let me know in the comments if that is preferable.
Additional Details
My tickets will be a single-ticket by an affiliated airline on a code-share.
We live within the US, and will be traveling abroad. My question is specifically about re-entry back to the US, as BOS/EWR/JFK are not our final destination.
What I already know
I'm pretty confident I know about #3, #5 and #6.
(#3,#5) Based on my personal experience, in both EWR and JFK with Delta, drop the bag outside customs, and it gets transferred.
With JetBlue at JFK, must walk to JetBlue's terminal, stand in the check-in line again. (This is what I'm trying to avoid)
Why I'm asking?
In early 2024, arriving from abroad through JFK, we had to drag our luggage to another terminal, and stand in line for JetBlue to check-in our luggage.
I'm trying to avoid hauling luggage across terminals after arriving in the US (I understand that terminal switching will be needed, that much I found), but can't find details about baggage re-check, neither in the airline's nor the airport's websites, and forum / community driven answers are all over the place.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

UPDATED ANSWER BASED ON COMMENTS

Thus, the airline that checked us in did not tag the luggage to the final destination.

If that's what really happened, than you appear to be solving the wrong problem. The screw up happened at check-in or at booking, not at the US entry point. On a single PNR, it is highly unusual that bags are not checked through to the final destination. It's hard to tell what went wrong without knowing your exact itinerary but this sounds like either the check-in agent was incompetent (or lazy) or something was fishy with the itinerary itself. No US entry point will allow you to drop after customs if the bags are not checked through.
The weird thing here is that checking through is often the easiest part of code shares (while getting boarding passes can be more complicated). Example: I recently checked in in Jakarta with ANA for a CGK->NRT->SFO->EWR monstrosity followed by EWR->BOS on a separate PNR.  We had no problem at all checking our bags through all the way from CGK to BOS. Yes, we had to collect them at SFO and drop them again after customs, but that was it.

JetBlue doesn't travel internationally

Incorrect. We flew BOS<->CDG just a couple of months ago on Jet Blue metal (lovely experience). Bag tagging is based on interlining agreements and most airlines have a sizable amount of interlining partners and it is VERY unusual to end up with non-interlining airlines on a single PNR.
Original answer to the question as asked
BOS:
All international flight that do not originate from a preclearance airport arrive in Terminal E. That's where you go through immigration, collect baggage and go through customs. Baggage drop for checked-through luggage is right after customs.
Delta domestic departs from Terminal A which is a bit of a hike so the best option is the Terminal shuttle bus. Route 11, 55, 66 or 88. You want to make sure it says "all Terminals" or "Terminal A" on the bus. At Terminal A you have to go through security again. Lines can be long especially early in the morning and TSA PreCheck is often very helpful there.
New York
I have done a lot of arrivals in EWR with United and it's very similar to Boston, i.e. bag drop right after customs exit. There are two immigration points in EWR and I'm not sure which one Delta is using. Between Terminals you can either walk or take the Air Train
I have little experience with JFK
Note that nothing is ever guaranteed: processes can change or there can be temporary interruptions and/or rerouting.

Thanks! Any idea whether JetBlue has baggage recheck spots in Terminal E in BOS?

@Lockszmith: I would assume so since all airlines tend to use the same recheck spot, but I haven't done with Jet Blue recently.

That was my problem, I assumed so as well, got disillusioned (see the comments and the updated post)

@Lockszmith: it appears you are attacking the wrong problem. See edit.

Maybe, what I took out of asking this question was that this is a rare occurrence, as it is completely misunderstood, and it might, possibly, be isolated to JetBlue, as those who actually responded were mostly flying with Delta, and never encountered with this issue regardless of where. I might pass through BOS, but I'll do it with Delta and not JetBlue on this international arrival.

I'm not sure I'll accept this as a 'screw up' as much as this is a messed up system. On the check-in desk, we were told that this would happen - not fully understanding what they meant until we arrived. When the person explained that we'll need to pick up and transfer them to a different temrinal - I was assuming they talked about re-checking, like we did with United and Delta many times, but alas, all she did was explain it to us, it was upon me to understand - and I finally understood - legs first.

@Lockszmith: Something went sideways here but without telling us the exact itinerary and how it was booked we can't assess what happened or help you avoiding this in the future. It's not normal or an indicator of a "screwed up system" and I don't think it has anything to do with Jet Blue. You have been repeatedly asked to provide this information but so far refused to do so. Do you want help or do you just want to rant ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
